Rendering Issue
I am wokring on R Quarto, and all of a sudden I am getting the following error/ halting of execution: ==> quarto preview Class.6_Quarto.qmd --to html --no-watch-inputs --no-browse
processing file: Class.6_Quarto.qmd
|..........................................          |  80% [unnamed-chunk-2]Error in render():
! unused arguments (visible = TRUE, envir = parent.frame())
Backtrace:

global .main()
execute(...)
rmarkdown::render(...)
knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
knitr:::process_file(text, output)
...
evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
knitr:::knit_print.default(x, ...)
evaluate (local) normal_print(x)

Quitting from lines 53-68 [unnamed-chunk-2] (Class.6_Quarto.qmd)
Execution halted
My code is correct as it runs smoothly without errors, however, I am unsure as to what all that is from No. 1 to 25 above!
HELP PLEASE!
B
I just want to render the document!
